# How do I find first occurence of a particular event for the list of users in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

I have to find the first occurrence of a particular event for the list of users in splunk.

eg: I have a list of users say 10 from another query.

I am using the below query to find date of the first mail sent by customer 12345. How do I find the same for a list of customer that I get from another query?

```
index=abc appname=xyz "12345" "*\"SENT\"}}"|reverse|table _time|head 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `stats`.

```
index=abc appname=xyz "12345" "*\"SENT\"}}" | stats first(_time)
```

Comment: i don want to pass "12345" in search query, instead pass custId from another search query

Comment: Then replace "12345" with a subsearch that returns a custId.

`index=abc appname=xyz [index=foo | return custId] "*\"SENT\"}}" | stats first(_time)`